Boy is sucked into a book cartoon
It's an old cartoon that I have seen when I was a kid, I remember certain moments but I just can't find the name of the damn movie. It's about a boy that get's into a book, where he becomes a prince of a kingdom or something, I remember that he has a dog that exists in the world of the book as well. And there are battles with participation of humanoid dinosaurs or something, and I am pretty sure that it's not The Neverending Story.
Year: Something like the 90's-80's. It was entirely animated.

How old was the movie ?

Something like the 90's-80's

Did it also contain live-action scenes? Or was it entirely animated?

Pagemaster?

@CoreyOgburn I was thinking Pagemaster as well.

Entirely animated.

Could it be the Phantom Tollbooth animated movie or Puff the Magic Dragon?

No, sorry, but it's not.

Sounds like a movie I saw as a kid called "The Pagemaster"




No, I am sorry but it is not the Pagemaster. The Pagemaster had live-action scenes, and I am pretty sure that no humanoid dinosaurs are present  in this movie.
